# Unable to generate six plots in one layout

Tags: r, plot

I would like to generate 6 plots in one layout, but my code generates only the last plot. This is my code:

```
i<-c(500,1500,2500)
for(n in i)
{
  par(mfrow = c( 6, 1 ))
  window<-333
  Filename2<-paste("/home/blabla/Bilder/6Fenster",n,".png",sep="")

  png(filename=Filename2,width = 800,height = 600)  

  plot(datalist[n:(n+window-1),1],type="l",col="blue",xlab=n+window,ylab="values")

  x.specR<-spectrum(datalist[n:(n+window-1),1],plot=FALSE)
  plot((1:180),x.specR$spec,type="l",xlab="Frequenz",ylab="Frequenz")  

  hfft<-hanning.window(333)*datalist[n:(n+window-1)]
  x.specHF<-spectrum(hfft,plot=FALSE)
  plot((1:180),x.specHF$spec,type="l",xlab="Frequenz",ylab="Frequenz")

  m<-acf(datalist[n:(n+window-1),1],lag.max=333,plot=FALSE)$acf[-1]
  plot(m,type="l",ylim=c(-1,1),axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
  axis(1,at=333/(1:333),labels=rev(333/(1:333)),axTicks(4))
  axis(2, at=c(-1,1))

  x.specA<-spectrum(m,plot=FALSE)
  plot((1:180),x.specA$spec,type="l",xlab="Frequenz",ylab="Frequenz")

  ha<-hanning.window(333)*m
  x.specHA<-spectrum(ha,plot=FALSE)
  plot((1:180),x.specHA$spec,type="l",xlab="Frequenz",ylab="Frequenz")

  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Just place par() after the png() line. When you use function png() new graphical device is used and old par() arguments are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `par` function should be called after you open the graphics device, which in this case is done with `png`. So you simply need to move that line.